# Why is it true that $\deg f_T = \dim V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T:V\to V$ such that $f_T = \prod_{i=1}^r (x-\lambda_i)^{k_i}$ and $\dim V_{\lambda_i} = k_i$.

Now, $$\sum_{i=1}^r k_i = \color{blue}{\deg f_T = \dim V}$$

Why is it true that the degree of the characteristic polynomial equals to the dimension of $V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to construct the characteristic polynomial is to take the matrix $A$ of $T$ and find $\operatorname{det}(A-tI)$ where $t$ is an indeterminant. Since $A$ and $I$ are $n\times n$ matricies, when taking the determinant we will have $n$ entries of $A-tI$ containing $t$ and each will be represented in the product, so the degree of the polynomial in $t$ must be $n$.

It is possible to be more rigorous with this following the definition of determinant and using induction, but hopefully this gives the intuition.